# Magento catalogsearch_result table not populated. Unknown column 'relevance' in 'order clause'

Tags: mysql, search, magento-1.9

On Magento 1.9.3.1 I am getting the error:
**Unknown column 'relevance' in 'order clause'**
When I perform a search.

Ive tried solutions such as changing the search type in configuration and re-indexing, but these have no effect.

I noticed that the **catalogsearch_result** table is not populated at all. This table has the relevance column defined within it.

If this table isn't being populated, could there be an issue with the database?
If the relevance column is unknown...could there be a code problem with the table not being joined when a search is performed maybe?

We have no real search module installed, but we do have the ExtendWare product sorting module installed which performs its own indexing of products so the user can sort product lists by several conditions. That should not affect this table though I believe (Im going to disable this module now and run further tests).

What could be causing the table not to be populated, and the relevance column not detected?

Comment: Wondering if you find a solution to your issue, as we are facing a similar problem?

Comment: If i remember correctly, the issue was solved when i removed the 'ExtendWare product sorting module'. This module provided its own complex sorting options/setup. We also had a stock filtering module that required some modification.
I would go through disabling custom modules...and also switching theme to rule out customised templates.